# How does the Z-Gate in sympy.physics.quantum.gate excatly work?

Tags: sympy, quantum-computing

If I run the following Python script:

```py
from sympy.physics.quantum import qapply
from sympy.physics.quantum.qubit import Qubit
from sympy.physics.quantum.gate import X, Z, ZGate
    
print("1a) Z(0)*Qubit('0')={0}".format(qapply(Z(0)*Qubit('0'))))
print("1b) Z(0)*Qubit('1')={0}\n".format(qapply(Z(0)*Qubit('1'))))
    
print("2a) Z(0)*Qubit('00')={0}".format(qapply(Z(0)*Qubit('00'))))
print("2b) Z(0)*Qubit('01')={0}".format(qapply(Z(0)*Qubit('01'))))
print("2c) Z(0)*Qubit('10')={0}".format(qapply(Z(0)*Qubit('10'))))
print("2d) Z(0)*Qubit('11')={0}".format(qapply(Z(0)*Qubit('11'))))
print("2e) Z(1)*Qubit('00')={0}".format(qapply(Z(1)*Qubit('00'))))
print("2f) Z(1)*Qubit('01')={0}".format(qapply(Z(1)*Qubit('01'))))
print("2g) Z(1)*Qubit('10')={0}".format(qapply(Z(1)*Qubit('10'))))
print("2h) Z(1)*Qubit('11')={0}".format(qapply(Z(1)*Qubit('11'))))
```

I get the following output:

```
1a) Z(0)*Qubit('0')=|0>
1b) Z(0)*Qubit('1')=-|1>
    
2a) Z(0)*Qubit('00')=|00>
2b) Z(0)*Qubit('01')=-|01>
2c) Z(0)*Qubit('10')=|10>
2d) Z(0)*Qubit('11')=-|11>
2e) Z(1)*Qubit('00')=|00>
2f) Z(1)*Qubit('01')=|01>
2g) Z(1)*Qubit('10')=-|10>
2h) Z(1)*Qubit('11')=-|11>
```

The ouput in line 1a) and 1b) are correct as my opinion is concerned but line 2b), 2c), 2f) and 2g) are wrong.
Where is the problem?

Any help is welcome.

Kind regards

Klaus

Comment: I'm using simpy version: 1.10.1

Comment: Are you trying to create a controlled Z gate?

Comment: No just a normal Z gate.

Answer (score 0):

Your output is correct, that is indeed how Z gate works.

I believe that your concerns are caused by notation misunderstanding. For example, in 2b:

> **Qubit('01')**

'01' in Qubit('01') means these are states of the qubits. (At the beginning you have 2-qubit register where qubit number 0 is in state |1> and qubit number 1 is in state |0>).

You can write this also in a form of:

```
Qubit('01') = |0> * |1>
```

> **Z(0)**

This "zero" here is not a state of a qubit, it is a number (index) of a qubit on which Z gate is applied.

So, after combining the two:

> **Z(0) * Qubit('01')**

You apply Z gate on qubit number 0 (rightmost qubit, the same which was in state |1>).

Z gate operates on one qubit (so qubit number 1 remains unchanged, and the gate flips phase of qubit number 0 only). You can denote this as:

```
Z(0) * Qubit('01') = Z(0) * (|0> * |1>) = |0> * Z|1> = |0> * -|1> = -|01>
```

..which is the same as shown by your output.